# Excel VBA - remove certain piece of string

Tags: excel, vba

I previously asked how I could check whether a piece of text contains a string, now I would like to delete that piece of string if it is found in that cell.

> If the value in column C is different from column W, I check whether
>   column A contains "MIG", if it does I add it to the cell, if not I do
>   nothing.

Because this macro is run everytime you save, if you were to edit the values in W & C to make them match then column A will still say "MIG".

> So when the document is saved, the macro will now see column C & W are
>   the same and if it contains "MIG" it should delete "MIG" from the
>   cell.

### Sample

```
If shtVO.Cells(Row, 3).Value <> shtVO.Cells(Row, 23).Value Then
  If shtVO.Cells(Row, 1).Value Like "*MIG*" Then
  Else
    shtVO.Cells(Row, 1).Value = shtVO.Cells(Row, 1).Value + "MIG"
  End If
Else
  If shtVO.Cells(Row, 3).Value = shtVO.Cells(Row, 23).Value Then
    If shtVO.Cells(Row, 1).Value Like "*MIG*" Then
        .....              
    End If
  End If
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand your logic, but to clear a cell value use

```
shtVO.Cells( ... ).ClearContents
```

EDIT

Use of `Replace`

```
shtVO.Cells( ... ).Value = Replace(shtVO.Cells( ... ).Value, "MIG", "")
```

The rest of your comment deals with the possibility that you are left with double space after replaceing `MIG`
Eg `"Fisrt MIG second"`  --> `"Fisrt  second"`

Comment: No I don't want to clear the cell, because it might contain other information too. I saw something about Replace() but when I record it, it creates a waay to complicated piece of code.

Comment: This is what I found
`If Cel Like "*" & Word & "*" Then    
            Cel = Replace(Cel, Word, "")    
           'To remove the double space that follows ..     
            Cel = Replace(Cel, "  ", " ")    
        End If`

Comment: The code is different compared to mine, but in all it's the same right?

Comment: Yes (if you nmean your comment code, not your answer), just uses a coded string rather than a variable

Comment: I meant my answer :) but I think I will use this code instead of mine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Replace() function:

```
If shtVO.Cells(Row, 1).Value Like "*MIG*" Then
   shtVO.Cells(Row, 1)=Replace(shtVO.Cells(Row, 1),"MIG","")
End If
```

Comment: Is this the same as my solution?

Comment: No.  `Replace` is a string function, working on the first parameter.  `Range.Replace` is a method, the same as using `Search/Replace` on a selection in Excel

Comment: So all in all it does the same?

Comment: My intuition says that Replace() is faster

Answer (score 0):

```
If shtVO.Cells(Row, 1).Value Like "*MIG*" Then
    shtVO.Cells(Row, 1).Replace What:="MIG", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
End If
```

This works too :)